# Error in plot_model(type="diag") : arguments imply differing number of rows error

Tags: r, plot, sjplot

I was doing a regression analysis and made regression model with this code,

```
regrs_2 <- lm(gii.score ~ hof.pdi + hof.idv + hof.mas + hof.uai + hof.ltowvs + 
                hof.ivr + ctnt.dummy.asia + ctnt.dummy.europe + ctnt.dummy.noram + 
                ctnt.dummy.africa + ctnt.dummy.oceania, data = data)
library(sjPlot)
plot_model(regrs_2, type="diag")
```

and run this code:

```
sjPlot::plot_model(regrs_2,type="diag")
```

At this time, an error occurred, saying:

```
Error in data.frame(x = fitted_, y = res_) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 61, 60**
```

But when I changed the `type=` argument of `plot_model` from `"diag"` to `"std"` or `"est"` there is no error.

How can I resolve this problem?

This is my `data`:

```
structure(list(X = c(4L, 5L, 11L, 31L, 32L, 41L, 57L, 91L, 93L, 
94L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 
46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 58L, 59L, 
60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 
73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 
86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 92L), ctnt = structure(c(6L, 3L, 6L, 
5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("남아메리카", 
"북아메리카", "아시아", "아프리카", "오세아니아", "유럽"), class = "factor"), 
    c_code = c(7L, 20L, 34L, 61L, 62L, 90L, 351L, 971L, 994L, 
    995L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 27L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 36L, 39L, 40L, 
    41L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 51L, 52L, 54L, 55L, 
    56L, 57L, 58L, 60L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 81L, 82L, 84L, 86L, 
    91L, 92L, 98L, 212L, 213L, 223L, 226L, 233L, 234L, 250L, 
    251L, 255L, 256L, 260L, 263L, 352L, 353L, 354L, 355L, 356L, 
    357L, 358L, 359L, 370L, 371L, 372L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 380L, 
    381L, 382L, 385L, 387L, 420L, 421L, 502L, 503L, 506L, 507L, 
    593L, 598L, 852L, 868L, 876L, 880L, 962L, 966L, 972L), country = structure(c(73L, 
    27L, 80L, 6L, 43L, 86L, 71L, 3L, 8L, 33L, 16L, 25L, 87L, 
    79L, 37L, 62L, 11L, 32L, 40L, 47L, 72L, 82L, 7L, 36L, 24L, 
    81L, 65L, 70L, 34L, 68L, 58L, 4L, 13L, 17L, 19L, 91L, 55L, 
    69L, 63L, 77L, 84L, 49L, 51L, 92L, 18L, 42L, 66L, 44L, 61L, 
    2L, 56L, 15L, 35L, 64L, 74L, 30L, 83L, 88L, 93L, 94L, 54L, 
    45L, 41L, 1L, 57L, 22L, 31L, 14L, 53L, 52L, 29L, 59L, 5L, 
    10L, 89L, 76L, 60L, 21L, 12L, 23L, 78L, 38L, 28L, 20L, 67L, 
    26L, 90L, 39L, 85L, 48L, 9L, 50L, 75L, 46L), .Label = c("Albania", 
    "Algeria", "Arab countries", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", 
    "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bangladesh", "Belarus", "Belgium", 
    "Bosnia", "Brazil", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Canada", 
    "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Cyprus", 
    "Czech Rep", "Denmark", "Dominican Rep", "Ecuador", "Egypt", 
    "El Salvador", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Finland", "France", 
    "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Great Britain", "Greece", 
    "Guatemala", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", 
    "Indonesia", "Iran", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", 
    "Japan", "Jordan", "Korea South", "Latvia", "Lithuania", 
    "Luxembourg", "Malaysia", "Mali", "Malta", "Mexico", "Moldova", 
    "Montenegro", "Morocco", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Nigeria", 
    "Norway", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", 
    "Portugal", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Saudi Arabia", 
    "Serbia", "Singapore", "Slovak", "South Africa", "Spain", 
    "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Trinidad and Tobago", 
    "Turkey", "U.S.A.", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "Uruguay", "Venezuela", 
    "Vietnam", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = "factor"), hof.pdi = c(44L, 
    NA, 24L, 11L, 39L, 31L, 28L, 40L, NA, NA, 12L, NA, 13L, NA, 
    26L, 11L, 30L, 33L, 17L, 20L, 43L, 9L, 2L, 10L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 
    33L, 10L, 29L, 41L, 19L, 34L, 28L, 32L, 41L, 1L, 45L, 5L, 
    37L, 29L, 21L, 26L, 35L, 40L, 38L, 22L, 25L, 35L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 13L, 6L, NA, NA, 23L, 
    NA, 8L, 35L, 14L, 15L, 13L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 42L, NA, 36L, 
    NA, 24L, 1L, 46L, 31L, 10L, 46L, 39L, 27L, 33L, 18L, 16L, 
    40L, NA, NA, 3L), hof.idv = c(21L, NA, 25L, 46L, 4L, 19L, 
    13L, 20L, NA, NA, 44L, NA, 47L, NA, 17L, 44L, 40L, 38L, 44L, 
    41L, 14L, 35L, 28L, 45L, 39L, 38L, 36L, 32L, 34L, 6L, 14L, 
    23L, 20L, 10L, 3L, 2L, 12L, 15L, 42L, 9L, 9L, 23L, 7L, 9L, 
    9L, 24L, 4L, 22L, 23L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 32L, 37L, NA, NA, 30L, NA, 33L, 14L, 32L, 37L, 32L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 11L, NA, 16L, NA, 29L, 26L, 31L, 8L, 5L, 
    1L, 43L, 18L, 11L, 6L, 21L, 9L, NA, NA, 27L), hof.mas = c(11L, 
    NA, 16L, 33L, 20L, 19L, 9L, 27L, NA, NA, 26L, NA, 34L, NA, 
    31L, 2L, 28L, 17L, 44L, 40L, 16L, 40L, 42L, 37L, 3L, 24L, 
    43L, 36L, 37L, 16L, 39L, 30L, 23L, 7L, 36L, 41L, 25L, 36L, 
    32L, 22L, 10L, 46L, 14L, 15L, 37L, 30L, 25L, 17L, 27L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 25L, 38L, NA, NA, 
    21L, NA, 6L, 15L, 4L, 45L, 8L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17L, NA, 15L, 
    NA, 31L, 1L, 12L, 15L, 5L, 18L, 35L, 13L, 31L, 32L, 38L, 
    29L, NA, NA, 21L), hof.uai = c(43L, NA, 37L, 17L, 14L, 36L, 
    3L, 27L, NA, NA, 14L, NA, 13L, NA, 4L, 18L, 42L, 37L, 35L, 
    30L, 39L, 20L, 28L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 16L, 41L, 25L, 38L, 35L, 
    37L, 31L, 37L, 33L, 31L, 10L, 12L, 15L, 32L, 24L, 40L, 36L, 
    8L, 8L, 11L, 28L, 21L, 27L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 28L, 9L, NA, NA, 44L, NA, 21L, 36L, 25L, 23L, 
    22L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 40L, NA, 33L, NA, 29L, 17L, 2L, 42L, 
    37L, 37L, 26L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 5L, 22L, NA, NA, 34L), hof.ltowvs = c(50L, 
    43L, 29L, 8L, 38L, 27L, 14L, 9L, 37L, 22L, 21L, 2L, 12L, 
    19L, 26L, 41L, 51L, 39L, 35L, 37L, 32L, 47L, 36L, 31L, 20L, 
    33L, 20L, 22L, 52L, 11L, 10L, 7L, 25L, 16L, 2L, 5L, 24L, 
    13L, 18L, 46L, 17L, 55L, 1L, 34L, 54L, 31L, 30L, 3L, 3L, 
    12L, 7L, 13L, 23L, 2L, 6L, NA, 19L, 10L, 15L, 4L, 40L, 10L, 
    14L, 37L, 28L, NA, 22L, 42L, 51L, 42L, 51L, 45L, 37L, 50L, 
    53L, 32L, 48L, 35L, 44L, 44L, 49L, NA, 7L, NA, NA, NA, 12L, 
    37L, 2L, NA, 28L, 5L, 21L, 22L), hof.ivr = c(10L, 25L, 29L, 
    50L, 24L, 33L, 20L, 21L, 11L, 19L, 47L, 37L, 47L, 43L, 34L, 
    47L, 40L, 32L, 18L, 17L, 10L, 45L, 43L, 48L, 49L, 53L, 38L, 
    16L, 26L, 31L, 58L, 42L, 41L, 47L, 55L, 2L, 40L, 27L, 52L, 
    31L, 30L, 27L, 16L, 22L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 26L, 13L, 19L, 28L, 
    8L, 51L, 56L, 23L, 31L, 24L, 35L, 27L, 15L, 39L, 44L, 46L, 
    5L, 45L, 49L, 40L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 9L, NA, 5L, 4L, 15L, 10L, 
    20L, 29L, 16L, 15L, NA, 57L, NA, NA, NA, 36L, 7L, 54L, NA, 
    10L, 28L, 35L, NA), gii.score = c(39.32, 28.91, 49.07, 55.22, 
    29.79, 37.81, 46.61, 40.06, 30.1, 33.83, 55.73, 30.6, 60.1, 
    37.45, 40.28, 61.58, 50.91, 53.59, 43, 46.4, 38.2, 68.3, 
    54.07, 62.42, 57.7, 62.4, 53.8, 40.16, 57.05, 34.87, 38.03, 
    34.3, 34.95, 41.2, 36.41, 22.77, 45.98, 31.05, 55.92, 59.36, 
    38.1, 53.97, 56.26, 38.35, 47.47, 31.74, 23.07, 28.37, 33.19, 
    24.38, 28.37, 28.68, 28.04, 23.72, 30.09, 24.17, 27, 27.65, 
    24.64, 22.52, 59.02, 59.13, 57.02, 30.74, 50.48, 43.51, 59.97, 
    42.16, 42.26, 45.51, 52.81, 40.53, 37.31, 38.23, 36.45, 36.47, 
    41.23, 41.7, 32.31, 51.32, 42.99, 28.84, 29.31, 38.59, 36.8, 
    26.87, 35.76, 57.23, 32.18, 29.95, 23.71, 33.78, 40.65, 53.54
    ), ctnt.dummy.asia = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), ctnt.dummy.europe = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ctnt.dummy.noram = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), ctnt.dummy.africa = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ctnt.dummy.oceania = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ctnt.dummy.souam = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-94L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What is `plot_model`? Please add details, which `library`s do you use etc., you may want to read: [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: plot_model is the function in sjPlot package

Comment: Ok, but we need your help to reproduce your problem. Making data available as images leads nowhere. You may really want to read the link I gave you carefully. Please make a minimal self-contained example that enables us to reproduce your problem on our machine by copy-paste your code and data.

Comment: I edited my question. It is my first question. so it would be incomplete. sorry.. TT

Comment: Well done!! Unfortunately I could only locate the error more precisely, see my answer. Maybe someone else can tell you more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspecting the code of the `sjPlot::plot_model` function reveals that `sjPlot:::plot_diag_linear` method is used and yields the error.

```
# sjPlot:::plot_diag_linear(regrs_2, geom.colors="red", dot.size=1, line.size=1)
# # Error in data.frame(x = fitted_, y = res_) : 
# #   arguments imply differing number of rows: 61, 60
```

Going a level deeper into the code we get to the plot list, where `sjPlot:::diag_qq` is failing.

```
sjPlot:::diag_vif(regrs_2)
```

[image]

```
# sjPlot:::diag_qq(regrs_2, dot.size=1, line.size=1)  ## FAILS!
# # Error in data.frame(x = fitted_, y = res_) : 
# #   arguments imply differing number of rows: 61, 60
```

```
sjPlot:::diag_norm(regrs_2, geom.colors="red")
# Warning message:
#   Removed 101 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

```
sjPlot:::diag_ncv(regrs_2, dot.size=1, line.size=1)
# `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Also warnings are thrown. The issue might be due to statistical reasons, since the example on `?sjPlot::plot_model` is working fine.

Only a partial answer, I know, hoping to help you somehow.